# How can I delete all objects in a json array by its keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have json like this:

```
json = [ 
   { 
      "value1":"3863",
      "value2":"4567"
   },
   { 
      "value1":"4456",
      "value2":"87687"
   },
   { 
      "value1":"98494",
      "value2":"4534"
   },   
]
```

What I need is to delete value2 so the json would look like:

```
json = [ 
   { 
      "value1":"3863"
   },
   { 
      "value1":"4456"
   },
   { 
      "value1":"98494"
   },   
]
```

I have tried to use

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
{    
  delete json["value2"];   
}
```

but it doesn´t work.

Is there any way of doing that ?

Comment: `delete json[i]["value2"];`. I would prefer `const result = json.map(({ value1 }) => ({ value1 }));` though.

Comment: You are missing index 'i'; delete json[i]['value2']

Comment: Thanks everyone, it works fine with both options. json.map and with the one I was trying to use (delete) in which I was missing the index i.

Answer (score 1):

```
const json = [ 
   { 
      "value1":"3863",
      "value2":"4567"
   },
   { 
      "value1":"4456",
      "value2":"87687"
   },
   { 
      "value1":"98494",
      "value2":"4534"
   },   
];

json.forEach(item => delete item.value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `map`.

```js
json = [ 
  { 
     "value1":"3863",
     "value2":"4567"
  },
  { 
     "value1":"4456",
     "value2":"87687"
  },
  { 
     "value1":"98494",
     "value2":"4534"
  }
];

console.log(json.map(({value1}) => ({value1})));
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current syntax:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
{    
  delete json[i].value2;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have missed `i` usage in accessing json array elements:

```
for(var i = 0; i < js.length; i++)
{    
  delete json[i]["value2"];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the iterator `i`:

`delete json[i]["value2"];`

```js
var json = [ 
   { 
      "value1":"3863",
      "value2":"4567"
   },
   { 
      "value1":"4456",
      "value2":"87687"
   },
   { 
      "value1":"98494",
      "value2":"4534"
   },   
];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {    
  delete json[i]["value2"];   
}

console.log(json);
```